# Create multiple columns in table based on the first rows output

Tags: php

I just set up an simple PHP script that echos 10 weeks based on todays date, 5 weeks forward, and 5 weeks backward.

The first `<TR>` works like a charm, it echo's all the `<TD>` with the corresponding week number. The problem is that I'd like it to echo the week number in multiple rows and then look up how many hours that have been reportet that week. How could i possible duplicate the number of `<TD>` from the first `<TR>` and keep the value of $from in each row so that I can calculate the hours for that week later on?

The current output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
/  *******  / W10 / W11 / W12 / W13 / W14 / W15 / W16 / W17 / W18 / W19 /                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
/ PROJECT 1 / 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The output I'd like to get:

```
[-5 WEEKS] / [+5 WEEKS]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
/  *******  / W10 / W11 / W12 / W13 / W14 / W15 / W16 / W17 / W18 / W19 /                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
/ PROJECT 1 /  1h /  4h /  1h /  4h /  3h /  8h /  3h /  4h /  1h /  8h /
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
/ PROJECT 2 /  4h /  2h /  2h /  1h /  8h /  3h /  8h /  3h /  4h /  7h /
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
/ PROJECT 3 /  1h /  3h /  4h /  1h /  5h /  2h /  7h /  1h /  7h /  5h /
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My code:

```
<?php
//Get current date, and go 5w forward
$now = new DateTime;
$now->modify("+5 week");

//Get current date, and go 5w backward
$from = new DateTime;
$from->modify("-5 week");
$from->modify("thursday this week"); // see ISO 8601 

echo '<table class="view-calendar" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">';
    echo '<tbody>';
        //The first row with week numbers
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td style="background: #f2f2f2">';
                echo '';
            echo '</td>';
            while($from < $now) {
                echo '<td valign="top">';
                    echo 'v'.$from->format('W');
                echo '</td>';
            $from->modify("+1 week");
            }
        echo '</tr>';
        //The rest of the rows with project hours in each column
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>';
                echo 'Project 1';
            echo '</td>';
            // ECHO THE REST OF <TD> based on week from first row
        echo '</tr>';
    echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: where does the data "Project 1" and "1h" come from and in what form?

Comment: @Jeff: Right now it's only entered manually, but later on it's supposed to come from sql.

Comment: basicly you'd just need to set back `$from` and do the loop again. The rest then depends on how the actual data looks like. Idealy you'd have a 2-dimensional array `$projects['id']['weeknumber'] = $hours` which would make it easy to fetch the data based on a weeknumber in your loop.

Comment: @Jeff, True! Tried it and it works. Would you like it to be the solution? Then put it as a post and I'll mark it as done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hoping it will help

```
<?php
//Get current date, and go 5w forward
$now = new DateTime;
$now->modify("+5 week");

//Get current date, and go 5w backward
$from = new DateTime;
$from->modify("-5 week");
$from->modify("thursday this week"); // see ISO 8601 

echo '<table class="view-calendar" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">';
    echo '<tbody>';
        //The first row with week numbers
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td style="background: #f2f2f2">';
                echo '';
            echo '</td>';
            while($from < $now) {
                echo '<td valign="top">';
                    echo 'v'.$from->format('W');
                echo '</td>';
            $from->modify("+1 week");
            }
        echo '</tr>';
        //The rest of the rows with project hours in each column
        $project=1;
        while($project<10) {
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>';
                    echo 'Project '.$project;
                echo '</td>';
                $from->modify("-11 week");
                   while($from < $now) {
                    echo '<td valign="top">';
                        echo 'v'.$from->format('W');
                    echo '</td>';
                $from->modify("+1 week");
                }
                // ECHO THE REST OF <TD> based on week from first row
            echo '</tr>';
            $project++;
        }
    echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand what you want in each cell, but something like this will give you the structure.

```
<snip> 
for ($i=1, $i<4, $i++) {  
echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>';
                echo 'Project ' . $i;
            echo '</td>';
            from->modify("-10 week");
            while($from < $now) {
                echo '<td valign="top">';
                //This is where I don't understand what you want. Where is the hourly data coming from?
                echo 'v'.$from->format('W');
                echo '</td>';
                $from->modify("+1 week");
            }
    echo '</tr>';
    }
<snip>
```